# Contact Print Summary - how can I customize?

Tags: contacts, core, printing

is it possible to customize the Contact Print Summary?
I would like to select the fields to be printed and manage the print templates by inserting for example the organization logo and the footer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. The Print Summary action just displays what is on the Summary tab and I don't think you can customise that.

If you want to get specific fields you would have to use a report or a search to customise the fields printed. The report would also allow you to customise the header.

Comment: do you think there might be an alternative solution? For example a report where you can select the fields...I don't know... Thank you.

Comment: On most of the reports you can select fields which show. Probably the Constituent Report is the place to start for the things on the summary tab. When you have got what you want, then you can save a copy of your customised report for future use. But there are other contact reports that might be a good starting point depending on exactly what you want. Have a play.